# Laravel - Multiple language files at custom locations

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, localization

Is there a way to have multiple language files for the same language? I know that it would work if you have different packages, however i have a own plugin system. Is there a way to load additional language files on runtime?

Comment: I can't downvote this question, but I would if I could. We simply need more detail to be able to help you. Kind of odd to offer a bounty and skimp on the details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you do this (inside `app/start/global.php` or where you prefer)

```
Lang::addNamespace('namespace', '/your/custom/location');
```

then you should be able to

```
Lang::get('namespace::filename.localekey');
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a file for your plugin in the proper language directory

```
/app
    /lang
        /en
            myplugin.php
```

Then you can do

```
 echo Lang::get('myplugin.foobar');
```

where *foobar* is the key in the line that contains the locale

Comment: Sadly i can't do that for reasons of the flexibility. I need to have them at custom locations.

Comment: When you say "custom locations" what do you mean, specifically? Adding new language files "on runtime?" I also am not sure what you mean by that. Please clarify the question, and add detail about the "custom locations" if you can, please.

Answer (score 0):

Q: Is there a way to have multiple language files for the same language?

> A: Yes, many ways.

Q: I know that it would work if you have different packages, however i have a own plugin system.

> A: Unhandled Exception: What do you mean by this? You have a plugin system, ok, why would that prevent you from having multiple language files? What mechanism related to having "different packages" would somehow enable multiple language files for the same language?

Q: Is there a way to load additional language files on runtime?

> A: Javascript?
>
> Actual Answer: Have you seen this package? https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization - it might help you out quite a bit. Without more information that's about as specific as I can get.

Answer (score 0):

I found this way:

In `AppServiceProvider.php`:

```php
public function boot()
{
    // ...

    app('translator')->addNamespace('shared', base_path() . '/src/Domain/Shared/resources/lang/');

    // ...
}
```

Then in any blade file:

```php
{{ __('shared::langfile.key-in-the-file') }}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add custom translation file but use translation keys in a same way as default translation keys, working on laravel 9
in app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php

```
public function boot()
{
    ...

    // Add deprecated lang strings
    if(method_exists($this, 'loadJSONTranslationsFrom')) {
        $this->loadJSONTranslationsFrom(lang_path().'/deprecated');
    }

    ...
}
```

Lang folder:

```
lang
    deprecated(any name registered earlier)
        en.json
```

If you want to do this in package, do the same in src/Providers/PackageServiceProvider.php

```
public function boot() {
    ...

    if(method_exists($this, 'loadJSONTranslationsFrom')) {
        $this->loadJSONTranslationsFrom(__DIR__.'/../../resources/lang');
        $this->loadJSONTranslationsFrom(__DIR__.'/../../resources/lang-other-folder');
    }
    ...
}
```

Try to clear cache if it doesn't work right away.

Lang file content(no comma after last item):

```
{
    "test": "123"
}
```

And using:

```
{{ __('test') }}
```

Good luck )